# making a function which accepts a list of objects and an anon function to go through them

Tags: javascript, jquery

the parameters are:

data:    an array of objects.

anonFunction:   a function which has the parameters which are the same as the params an object from data.

goal:

it will iterate through data, and fire off the anon function with new params each time.

Idea/Attempt:

```
 function special(data, executeFunction){
    var callback = function(){
       if(executeFunction){
          executeFunction();
       }
    }
    var d = JSON.parse(data);
    for( var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
       var object = d[i];
       callback(object);
    }
 }
```

Does that look about right?  The only issues i can see is that object is serialized.  So i would need to pass in only the values of the items, in the order.  Figure that might be accomplished by somehow.  Im not sure. :(

As you can see i have some gaps.

Edit:  Some sample data:

```
data = [{"url": "google.com", "type":"POST"}, {"url":"yahoo.com","type":"GET"}]
```

it would be broken down an iterate over url and type.
I would pass that into:

```
anonFunction(a,b){
     $.ajax({url:a, type:b});
}
```

so after executing my function with a list, and an anonfunction, it would with my sample, do a request to google and yahoo.

Edit2:

What the function would look like:

```
 //given data from above.
 special(data, function(a,b){
     $.ajax({url:a, type:b});
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `callback` function as defined doesn't accept any parameters. Later, you're passing your object into it, but it won't do anything with it.

I think you're overcomplicating it, though. You just need something like:

```
function special(data, callback){
  if(!callback) return;
  var d = JSON.parse(data);
  for( var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
    callback(d[i]);
  }
}

special(data, $.ajax);
```

As a bonus, in Coffeescript, this'd simply be something like:

```
$.ajax(settings) for settings in JSON.parse(data)
```

:)

Comment: That just might be what i am wanting.....   Pretty much im trying to do some testing with async stuff, so the callback would be any asnyc created function

Comment: Okay, well, if you need a generalized form, then just accept the function and call it by passing the parameters to it directly. No need to create a second wrapper function; you already have a function reference!

Comment: alright, I will test it out and confirm.  I want to make sure it is right before i assign an answer.  Thank you for your information, it is quite valued.

Comment: Is it possible to append code to the success function call of an async function?  in this case, $.ajax.  I was thinking there was a way to override success function with itself + 1 line of code.

Comment: Im making an async process limiter.  It is to only allow N number of ajax calls to be running at any given time.